# Will Selenium Webdriver become less popular in coming years?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, cypress, playwright

Lot of Automation engineers have shifted to new Web automation tools like Cypress, WebDriverIO, Pupeeter, Playwritght, Katalon Studio, AI tools like Testium, Functionize etc and i am still working on Java and Selenium, Cucumber Framework..

Will in coming time, Selenium/java become less popular for QA engineers and all code will be moved/re-written in newer tools ?

Comment: Yes, its popularity will drop from 83% to 45% over the next 4 years.  Actually I can't predict the future (that was a joke) and also there is no mechanism for actually measuring this outside of anecdotes. So while its a valid question and something I wonder about, its not a valid question for this site where a well defined question gets specific answers based on knowledge. So opinion based. Close.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically if you analyse this change of inclusion of new framework & compare with older one, following points will have to be taken into consideration:

1. New frameworks like Cypress, WebDriverIO, Pupeeter, Playwritght etc:

   - Change is expected as a part of progress
   - There are some advantage in terms of speed, maintenance, enhancement in framework so they have been introduced
   - Framework selection is based on the project requirements, stack already being used & many more parameters
   - User base for javascript has been increased significantly  & naturally frameworks base on javascript are getting more popularity
2. Old frameworks :

   - Since couple of decades selenium framework is there and you can see
     most mature too
   - Maturity comes with stability, continuous rolling out updates & support, large community support etc
   - Fact is many places selenium based automation has been already implemented using Java, Ruby, Python, C# or other language with Selenium and they will keep on using it
   - Because its not only fulfilling their requirements but to adapt and change whole automation would be time consuming process for them
   - People might be sometimes reluctant for sudden changes when it comes to cost which they have already invested and now invest more again from start for new tool/framework
   - Do not worry there will be always user base for old framework
3. Other side of the coin :

   - There are few frameworks like Robotium, Calabash was also introduced at some point of time
   - Where are they now? Does they have backed up by their own development team? Are they less successful to create large community base?
   - Those are now left behind and some stopped support too
4. From own expertise and being employable aspect :

   - Even though Robotium and Calabash are fallen behind still those requirements has been fulfilled by Appium for mobile these days (there are few more new framework but I will not go there)
   - You can sense what is still being followed:

     - Finding elements, good and efficient locator usage, interaction with them are still being use in automation which is not outdated still
     - Framework and their architecture got change and modified but its not total technology flip
     - If we could do, what we are doing with good understanding, will be ready for new framework all the time & that will keep us employable too